# Tidyverse, Perform math function using mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to figure out how to perform a basic math function on multiple columns using either mutate_all or mutate_at.  I need to convert a number by a decimal (divide each column by 10).  This is the second part after I use a summarise_at to obtain mean values for each column.
        cn<-c("tmin_1", "tmin_2", "tmin_3", "tmin_4", "tmin_5", 
        "tmin_6", "tmin_7", "tmin_8", "tmin_9", "tmin_10", "tmin_11", 
        "tmin_12")

```
    a<-data.frame(replicate(12,sample(1:10,6,rep=TRUE)))
    names(a)[1:12]<-cn
    a$"S"<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B")

    a2 <- a %>% 
        filter(S == "A") %>% 
        summarise_at(vars(tmin_1:tmin_12), funs(mean))
```

Works up to here. When I add "mutate_all(y=y/10)" at the end it doesn't work.

The above code returns a new object with 1 row and 12 columns, which is what I want.  The columns contain mean values.  Now I just need to divide each value by 10 to convert the number.  I tried mutate_all() but it is not working for me.  I'm not sure how to execute `/10` to each column.  I don't know how to refer to the columns.

ON a related note, can someone provide a simpler tidy way to generate the above example data frame?  I would like to create a table of random numbers in several columns, assign characters to a single column, and name each column in a single set pipes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'S' column is `character`, so may need `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
    filter(S == "A") %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ./10)
```

If it is on the 'a2'

```
a2 %>% 
    mutate_all(list(y =  ~ ./10))
```

Comment: Hi, That worked.  I added it and it indeed did divide each column by 10.  So, what exactly is the use of "~."?  Does that simply mean all columns within the object?

Comment: @Fishguy it is anonymous lambda function similar to `function(x) x/10`.  It is looping over. each column with `mutate_all` and then the  `.` is the column value for each of those columns

Comment: One last question.  So with the code mutate_all(list(y =  ~ ./10))" new columns are added at the end of the object.  This is ok but how whould I overwrite exisitng columns?

Comment: @Fishguy just do `mutate_all(~ ./10)` I was thinking that you need new columns that is the reason for `y=` in your question

Answer (score 0):

Note that base R often allows you to easily apply scalar operations to vectors of data.  For example, your df `a` which has 12 numeric columns and a single character column at the end.  Then you simply divide the numeric columns by 10.  This base operation would provide the desired result:

```
a[ , 1:12] <- a[ , 1:12] / 10
```

If the character column was not present the scalar operation would simply be:

```
a <- a / 10
```